# Pandas multi index loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe for graph edges with a multi index as such

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), ...], data=['v1', 'v2', 'v3', ...])
```

However doing a simple `.loc` fails:

```
df.loc[(1, 2)]       # error
df.loc[df.index[0]]  # also error
```

with the message `KeyError: 1`. Why does it fail? The index clearly shows that the tuple `(1, 2)` is in it and in the docs I see `.loc[]` being used similarly.

Edit: Apparently `df.loc[[(1, 2)]]` works. Go figure. It was probably interpreting the first iterable as separate keys?

Comment: your index is not a multiIndex. The index is a single index of tuples, which is why the second option works. Basically, wrapping the tuple inside a list does the job. If your index were a multiindex, I believe your first approach would work

Comment: Oh, I see.. I hate finding the solution only after I have asked for help. Maybe it will help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to wrap the key in another iterable like a list for it to use the whole tuple instead of its elements like so: `df.loc[[(1, 2)]]`.

Comment: This works, but returns 1-row `DataFrame`, not `Series`.